# deriving the probability $P(Y^{c}R) = P(Y^c) - P(Y^cR^c)$

Tags: probability

I'm having difficulty deriving the probability $P(Y^{c}R)$ to the following probability: 
$$P(Y^{c}R) = P(Y^c) - P(Y^cR^c) $$

Which rules were used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Y^c = (Y^c \cap R) \cup (Y^c \cap R^c)$ and that this union is disjoint (that is, $(Y^c \cap R) \cap (Y^c \cap R^c)=\varnothing$).

You should have some result about probabilities of disjoint events being additive, so $$P(Y^c) = P(Y^c \cap R) + P(Y^c \cap R^c).$$